# Delete Object From A Value

Tags: javascript

I have a object, in that object I have other objects (objectseption). Now I want to be able to delete one of those objects (the objects within the main object) from a ID value given. I'll show you what I mean:

```
object { 

   1 : { 
         id: 1,
         name: john
       },

   2: {
        id: 3,
        name: sam
      },

   3: {
       id: 5,
       name: ollie
    },

   4: {
       id: 12,
       name: nathan 
    }

}
```

Now let's say that I want to delete/remove Sam from the object, but all I have is Sam's **ID**. This is where I'm stuck. How do I remove Sam only having his **ID** (which is 3).

I'm quite new to javascript, and usually rely heavily on frameworks to complete a project - so when it comes to these simple things I get quite stuck!

**Any Help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate the objects properties, check, and remove:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (obj[key].id == 3) {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah dude u are awesome, so fast